# Using a parameter with Catel Command

Tags: wpf, command, catel

I tried using a parameter with Catel's Command:

```
public Command MyCommand { get; private set; }

MyCommand = new Command(MyCommand_Execute);

private void MyCommand_Execute(object parameter)
{
}
```

and get the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Catel.MVVM.Command.Command(System.Action, System.Func, object)'
>   has some invalid arguments

I followed the sample Catel code, any ideas?

Comment: I found that I can get this to work if I use Commmand<object>.

Answer (score 6):

The finalize this question with an actual answer:

Use the generic implementation of the Command class, which is Command:

```
public Command<int> MyCommand { get; private set; }

MyCommand = new Command<int>(MyCommand_Execute);

private void MyCommand_Execute(int parameter)
{
}
```